# TableHeaderView not responding to touches

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a custom subclass of UIView, designed in IB that contains a few labels and a button. 
There is an action for touchUpInside event on the button and the target is the custom view.

I am attaching this custom view to a self.tableView.tableHeaderView for a tableview in my UI.

The strange thing is this custom view is not responding to touches. I can see it nicely with all the labels and the button in side the table view, that means the table view handles and shows it correctly, however it is not responding to touches. 
I checked the whole view hierarchy and all the views involved have userInteractionEnabled as YES. 
If i drag some other controls into that custom view for example a switch, segmented control..they do not respond as well. It is like these controls in custom view are not registering touches.

It doesn't make any sense. I am out of ideas. Can you help to allow the touch event on the button to arrive to its parent view?

Comment: Try checking if the autolayout constraints of your custom view are set correctly in Interface Builder.

Comment: I have turned of autolayout, ie. I am using the good old spring and struts.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Oh..I don't remember anymore..I might possibly have added a UITapGestureRecognizer to it :)

Comment: Yeah, UITapGestureRecognizer is a good solution here. Another good solution is to add UIButton that will have the same frame as custom view and connect it with @IBAction - it works fine for me ('User Interaction Enabled'  property should be enabled for UIVIew and UIButton on a xib)

Answer (score 0):

What is a "headerTableView"? Do you mean a UITableViewHeaderFooterView? Have you tried setting userInteractionEnabled on the root UITableViewHeaderFooterView?

Comment: damn.. I have misstyped..I meant tableHeaderView property- the global tableview header view. I am going to fix that now.

Comment: Try setting `userInteractionEnabled = YES` on your `tableHeaderView`.

Comment: I paranoidly did checked it to be turn on on everything in IB and also in code for any possible view available. No help.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack that will detect a button touch and trigger touchUpInside programmatically:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) 
{
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    if let touch = touches.first, button.bounds.contains(touch.location(in: button)) {
        button.sendActions(for: UIControl.Event.touchUpInside)
    }
}
```

I don’t know what your real problem is because that button should work without this.